# Calculate population in SpatialPolygonDataFrame

Tags: r

I have a question regarding a calculation I have to do.

I have the following dataset:

- a SpatialPolygonDataFrame called `SPDF` which consists of polygons with numerous attributes

Since I intersected this `SPDF` previously I want to calculate the population based on the new shapes of every polygon.
I have in my `SPDF` a variable called `PopulationPerSQM` which is basically the population per square meters. All I need to do now, is going through every polygon inside the `SPDF` and simply calculate:
`PopulationPerSQM`*`Area`. However I do not know how to iterate through a SpatialPolygonDataFrame and to then calculate for each polygon inside it the population. Anybody has an idea how to do that or can link me to the solution please?

Comment: A reproducible example would be very helpful here.

Comment: Are you familiar with the str(SPDF) command and the $ and @ operators that would allow you to access different parts of the spatial polygon data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tomas: I got it using `SPDF$Population<-round(SPDF$aream2*SPDF$PopPerSQM)`